# const constructor and const object in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am stuck with gasp about const constructor in Dart (Flutter).

Supposed that I have StatelessWidget with const constructor

```
class ChildWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String myText;

  const ChildWidget(
      {this.myText = ''});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      myText
    );
  }
}
```

And using it in parent widget

```
class _ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {
  String myText = 'Hello World';
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const ChildWidget(myText: myText),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It shows error that myText is invalid const. But when I remove const keyword precede ChildWidget, everything will be OK. What happens? What are differences between have and does not have const keyword?

I supposed that const keyword will trigger const constructor in ChildWidget. Maybe Flutter implicitly creates normal constructor with the same argument such as const one and trigger this when not having const keyword?

Please explain it to me. Many thanks and have a good day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const` means "known at compile time". If you call a constructor with the `const` keyword, it will instead be created at compile time, and will be built into the application binary:

```dart
const child1 = ChildWidget(myText: "text");
const child2 = ChildWidget(myText: "text");
print(identical(child1, child2));  // prints "true"
```

Note, this only happens when the application is compiled in Ahead-of-time mode (AOT). In Flutter, this means "profile" or "release" mode.

The reason why your example fails is because `myText` is not known at compile time.

This can seem confusing, because you have typed `'Hello World'` which is clearly known at compile time, but the compiler cannot *prove* this, so it rejects it.

`myText` is declared as a `String`, but for dart to know that it is `const`, it must also be declared with the `const` keyword.

If you replace `String myText = "Hello World";` with:

```dart
static const myText = 'Hello World';
```

the compiler will know it is const and then you can use it in your `const ChildWidget()`

P.S. you are correct that Dart creates a non-`const` constructor alongside a `const` constructor. It is perfectly fine to not use `const` with a `const` constructor:

```dart
children: [
  ChildWidget(myText: myText)  // perfectly fine
]
```

Comment: Yeah. I get it now. Maybe Dart clone non-const from a const constructor with exactly parameters? I have just tested it with put @required annotation and both const and non-const constructor requires it.

Comment: Yes exactly, the `const` keyword on a constructor tells the dart compiler "this is something that can be made into a compile-time constant", but it can always be used like a regular constructor with the same parameters

Comment: I got it. Thank you a lot :D